# shares of stack problem with js and dynamic programming

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

The problem receives an input like [[500, 5, 1], [450, 2, 1], [400, 5, 1]], where each row represents a buyer. Each buyer has a value in position 0, which represents the amount they are willing to pay for an action. Position 1 represents the maximum number of actions they can buy, and position 2 represents the minimum number of actions they want to buy. The total number of available actions in this case is 8.

The goal is to assign actions to the buyers to obtain the maximum profit. In this case, the optimal solution is to assign 5 actions to the first buyer, 2 actions to the second buyer, and 1 action to the third buyer. This results in a maximum profit of 3800.

In the algorithm below, I traverse a matrix where the rows represent the buyer IDs, and the columns represent the number of actions. The first conditional verifies if the number of actions falls within the range specified by the buyer. If so, all the actions are assigned to that buyer if the previous buyer did not have a better offer. The second conditional checks if the number of actions is greater than the maximum number of actions that the buyer can afford. If it is, the algorithm assigns all the actions the buyer can afford and then obtains the remaining actions to achieve the maximum profit obtained previously with that number of actions, which are added to the result. The last if statement checks if the number of actions assigned to the buyer is less than their minimum requirement and if it is, just take the previous profit obtained with that number of actions.

The result of the algorithm was 3500 instead of 3800. I want to know why it is not giving me the expected result.

```
const buyers = [[500, 5, 1], [450, 2, 1], [400, 5, 1]]; // Each row represents a buyer: [value, maxActions, minActions]
const knapsackCapacity = 8; // Total number of available actions

const matrix = [];

// Initialize the matrix with 0s
for (let i = 0; i <= buyers.length; i++) {
  matrix[i] = new Array(knapsackCapacity + 1).fill(0);
}

// Fill the matrix with the maximum profit for each combination of buyers and available actions
for (let buyer = 1; buyer < matrix.length; buyer++) {
  const value = buyers[buyer - 1][0];
  const maxActions = buyers[buyer - 1][1];
  const minActions = buyers[buyer - 1][2];
  
  for (let actions = 1; actions < matrix[buyer].length; actions++) {
    if (actions <= maxActions && actions >= minActions) {
      // Assign all actions to the buyer if the previous buyer did not have a better offer
      matrix[buyer][actions] = Math.max(matrix[buyer - 1][actions], actions * value);
    } else if (actions > maxActions) {
      // Assign the maximum number of actions the buyer can afford and get the remaining actions to achieve the maximum profit obtained previously
      matrix[buyer][actions] = Math.max(matrix[buyer - 1][actions], matrix[buyer - 1][actions - maxActions] + maxActions * value);
    } else {
      matrix[buyer][actions] = matrix[buyer - 1][actions];
    }
  }
}

console.log(matrix);
console.log(matrix[buyers.length][knapsackCapacity]); // The maximum profit obtained
```

Comment: do you have an example of the wanted result?

Comment: wanted result is: solution is to assign 5 actions to the first buyer, 2 actions to the second buyer, and 1 action to the third buyer. This results in a maximum profit of 3800 because of 5*500+450*2+400*1.

Comment: what if the minimum is not reachable for all buyers?

Answer (score 0):

You could dispers all minimum acrions first and then take the largest profit until no more capacity is available.

```js
const
    buyers = [[500, 5, 1], [450, 2, 1], [400, 5, 1]], // [value, maxActions, minActions]
    result = [];

let capacity = 8;

buyers.sort(([a], [b]) => b - a);

for (let [value, maxActions, minActions] of buyers) {
    minActions = Math.min(minActions, capacity);
    result.push([value, maxActions - minActions, minActions]);
    capacity -= minActions;
}

let i = 0;
while (capacity) {
    let minActions = Math.min(result[i][1], capacity);
    result[i][1] -= minActions;
    result[i][2] += minActions;
    capacity -= minActions;
    i++;
    if (i >= result.length) break;
}

const profit = result.reduce((t, [p, , c]) => t + p * c, 0);

console.log(profit);
result.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```